# python - How to create a new columns based on calculations of one column. Calculation of UserAccountControl flags

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following sample data frame:

```
column1,column2,column3
tom,0100,544
tim,0101,514
ben,0899,1512
```

The third column contains the [useraccountcontrolflag](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/305144/how-to-use-the-useraccountcontrol-flags-to-manipulate-user-account-pro), and each line represents one user entry. The flags are cumulative. 
This means - disabled user account, the UserAccountControl is set to 514 (2 + 512). In my example - tim is disabled.

I would like to create a new column for each flag where it will assign the value 1 if the flag is set or 0 for not.

For the above example, the output will look like:

```
column1  column2  column3  DISABELDACCOUNT  NORMALUSER  PASSWORDNOTREQ  TEMP_DUPLICATE_ACCOUNT  SPECIALUSER
tom      100      544                0           1               1                      0            0
tim      100      512                0           1               0                       0            0
ben      899     1512                0           1               0                       0            1
```

Here is my python code - but it didn't work for my dataframe. It works only with one row ...

```
#!/bin/python
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np

def get_flags(number):
      df['DISABELDACCOUNT']=0
      df['NORMALUSER']=0
      df['PASSWORDNOTREQ']=0
      df['TEMP_DUPLICATE_ACCOUNT']=0
      df['SPECIALUSER']=0
      while number > 0:
             if number >= 1000:
                     df['SPECIALUSER']=1
                     number = number - 1000
                     continue
             elif number >= 512:
                     df['NORMALUSER']=1
                     number = number - 512
                     continue
             elif number >= 256:
                     df['TEMP_DUPLICATE_ACCOUNT']=1
                     number = number - 256
                     continue
             elif number >=32:
                     df['PASSWORDNOTREQ']=1
                     number = number - 32
                     continue
             elif number >=2:
                     df['TEMP_DUPLICATE_ACCOUNT']=1
                     number = number - 2
                     continue
df = pd.read_csv('data2.csv')
df['column3'].apply(get_flags)
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the column names differ from the Microsoft documentation that you quoted. But assuming that you are fine with renaming the column according to that docs, you can make use of numpy `bitwise_and`

```
df = pd.read_csv('data2.csv')
flags = {
    'SCRIPT'           : 0x0001,
    'ACCOUNTDISABLE'   : 0x0002,
    'HOMEDIR_REQUIRED' : 0x0008,
    'LOCKOUT'          : 0x0010,
    'PASSWD_NOTREQD'   : 0x0020,
    #.... (add more flags here as required, I just copy-pasted from the docs)
}   

for (f, mask) in flags.items():            
    df[f] = np.bitwise_and(df['column3'], mask) / mask
print(df)
```

This outputs:

```
  column1  column2  column3  SCRIPT  ACCOUNTDISABLE  HOMEDIR_REQUIRED  LOCKOUT  PASSWD_NOTREQD
0     tom      100      544     0.0             0.0               0.0      0.0             1.0
1     tim      101      514     0.0             1.0               0.0      0.0             0.0
2     ben      899     1512     0.0             0.0               1.0      0.0             1.0
```

Incidentally, checking for flags that have been stringed together as hexadecimal number using bitmask is a pretty common pattern.

Comment: Hi Santoso Thanks for your answer it was very helpful and I'm one step further. Unfortunately, I'm struggeling with the following error; `TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

I've defined the input type in the file.

`df = pd.read_csv('debug-file.txt', low_memory=False, dtype={"user_id": 'int'})`

Comment: Can you update the question again with the content of `debug-file.txt`? your `dtype` argument seems to specify a column called `user_id` which is not present in the original dataframe.

Comment: My guess is you have to specify `"column3":"int"` as well in your `dtype` argument because that column might not be parsed as an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the function you created to do what you want. Everytime you do for example `df['SPECIALUSER']=1` it assigns 1 to the whole column not only to the row you think you are targetting.
To assign each value to the correct row you have to assign values to each column seprately instead:

```
df['SPECIALUSER'] = np.where(df['column3'] >= 1000, 1, 0)
df['NORMALUSER'] = np.where((df['column3'] - 1000) >= 512, 1, 0)
...
```

I didn't understand exactly the logic you use to assign 1 and 0 but if you correct that and repeat what i wrote above for all the columns you need you should be able to get the result you are looking for.